# Refreshing the main page after closing a modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, thickbox

On a given webpage I have a link that opens a modal window using Thickbox. In that window I have a form which I use to save some data. After I submit the form, I close the modal window. Now my question is: can I refresh the main page after closing the modal window?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Call this after the form is submitted and before the window is closed:

```
window.opener.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is the div you show in modal mode. You have to call `tb_remove()` to close the modal window. So just use `location.reload();` before that call.

```
<div id="modalContent" style="display:none">
  <form>
    ...
  </form>
  <p style="text-align:center">
    <input type="submit" id="Login"value="Click to close"
      onclick="window.opener.location.reload();tb_remove()" />
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid I have to modify Thickbox source in order to add that piece of code.

Comment: Why? What makes you think that

Comment: Because I can't edit the source in order to add that code just for that page.

Answer (score 0):

Actually [Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) is no longer being maintained, so it might be better to use a different modal window. That being said, I know [Facebox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox) allows you to bind box open and close events like this:

```
$(document).bind('close.facebox', function() {
 // do something here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If using facebox simply add window.location.reload(); around line 148, so you end up with something like...
close: function() {
      $(document).trigger('close.facebox');
      window.location.reload();
      return false
    }

If still using Thickbox I'm sure it's just as easy. Do a search for "close" and add the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with the tinybox plugin:

http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/tinybox2/

```
var parentWindow = window;
$('#submit-deed-button').click(function() { 
    TINY.box.show({iframe:'submit_deed.html', closejs:function(){parentWindow.location.reload()}, post:'id=16',width:385,height:470,opacity:20,topsplit:3, boxid:'tinybox_container'}) 
});
```

The key is to pass in the parent window to the function as a JS var then you call location.reload() on that object